Angular template variable vs ngModel
I'm not exactly sure when for forms or in general I should use ngModel or template variables. Can anyone tell me?

It all depends on what your use case is.
Firstly, ngModel supports Two-way binding with [()] syntax, meaning youre able to sync the value in the view to the component and vice versa. While template referenced variables allows only One-way access (read-only).
Another advantage ngModel has over template referenced variables, is that it supports form validation features, while with template referenced variables, it only allows manual validation.

They are both communication ways in Angular.
NgModel

Creates a FormControl instance from a domain model and binds it to a form control element.

Explanation:
[(ngModel)]  is a part of the Angular FormsModule. If you have the FormsModule imported, you can use the extra functionality of ngModel. Doing so creates an NgForm and FormControl that you can use in more complicated reactive and dynamic forms and will track the field's status, e.g. dirty, touched. It will also allow you to place error validators on the field, as well as expose an Observable stream of value changes.
While a template reference variable

(...) is often a reference to a DOM element within a template. It can
also be a reference to an Angular component or directive or a web
component. (...)

Explanation: template variables and ViewChild to just grab an input element and interact with it as you would with vanilla JS is just fine as well, especially if your use case is something simple. This way you could avoid including the FormsModule in your module.
